# How can I make a navigation bar vertically?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a navigation bar and I need to make it vertical. My list items should be vertical too. I tried to use `writing mode` and `text orientation` but it's overflowing off the page. Then I used `transform: rotate(-90deg)` for my unordered list but it's going upwards. So this is my HTML:

```html
<div class="header-social">
  <nav class="header-nav-secondary">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">behance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">dribble</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">linkedin</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make it like this. [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqVfj.png)

Comment: What's wrong with using `transform: rotate(-90deg)`?

Comment: @j08691 The OP is referring to the vertical menu on the right side of the image, not the navbar at the top.

Comment: @Run_Script Aha! I didn't even see it it was so small, light, and insignificant

Answer (score 0):

`transform: rotate(-90deg)` is the way to go, but you also need to use `transform-origin` to define the "root position" of the rotation at the top right, `float` the contents of the navbar to the right and make the list items `inline-block`s in order to have them in one line.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-social {
  float: right;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: top right;
  background: #eee;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-social">
  <nav class="header-nav-secondary">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">behance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">dribble</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">linkedin</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: you can simplify lile this to avoid pixel values `transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%);
    transform-origin: top right;`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, true, thanks for the suggestion, I changed my snippet accordingly!